# QtDesigner 5.2.1 - Ubuntu-13.10. qtchooser configuration files not found

Tags: qt, ubuntu-13.10

I've just installed the Qt5.2.1 (`/opt/qt-5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc64`) on my Ubuntu 13.10. I previuosly installed a Qt5.1 in my home directory.
When call designer, an error raised

```
 designer: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
```

I've seen that this target points to a *qtchooser program*. In the docs it's used for to switch between different Qt versions. Very usefull as this configuration can be applied system wide.

I would like to configure it but based on the `qtchooser` manpage , the configuration files should be located at
*/etc/xdg/qtchooser/*.conf*. In Ubuntu 13.10 there's no such directory and no information about the file names and their internal structure but a line for the binaries path and one line for the library path, a default conf file that would contain the default path? 
I created the desired qtchooser directory with a *default.conf* file containing my *lib* and *bin* path. Nothing changed when I ran `qtchooser --list-version`, always the same list is displayed:

```
qtchooser --list-versions
```

outputs :

```
jeby6372@mercure:/opt$ qtchooser --list-versions
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
5
default
qt5
```

I don't understand where these informations are stored so that I could manage the swap beetween my 2 versions.

Or at least , is it possible to disconnect qtchooser without removing the Qt products?

Any Idea?

Comment: Do a "locate qtchooser" in command line. You should be seeing some *.conf files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Snowfish. Unfortunately has I faced a lot of problems with Unbuntu 13.10. I've swicthed my PC to debian-7.4. No more able to check your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 13.10, the configuration files are stored here:

```bash
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qtchooser/
```

I simply added new conf file, copying from one existing (e.g. `qt521.conf`) edited changed the path to the new QT5.2.1, configured qtchooser to use the new conf file with

```
export QT_SELECT=qt521
```

and now I can call qmake using the QT5.2.1 environment.